# Converting UserID to Member object [DISCORD4J]

Tags: member, userid, discord4j

I currently code a Discord bot in Java with Discord4j. Now, I want to get the mentioned user IDs (already did that) and convert them into Member object, but I don't know how to do it.

That's my code currently:

```
public static void run(MessageCreateEvent event) {
    if(event.getMessage().getUserMentionIds().toString() == "[]") {
        Utils.sendMessageToChannel("ERROR: No User got mentioned.", event);
    }
    Snowflake userMentions = Snowflake.of(event.getMessage().getUserMentionIds().toString());
    Member member = new Member(userMentions);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord4J does not allow the use of constructors on its entities and most objects. This is because all of the entities are built up from data from the cache and/or a rest request to discord.

To get a Member from a user ID you would do the following:

```
GatewayDiscordClient#getMemberById(guildId, userId).block();
```

If you just want the user, as Member requires the person be in the guild:

```
GatwayDiscordClient#getUserById(userId).block();
```

You can also do this reactively by (flat)mapping the Mono(s).